# Python Error by importing numpy module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently uninstalled and reinstalled python (and thus get the very latest version), but I'm getting this error when loading `numpy` or `matplotlib`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I tried to install pip, and then reinstall `matplotlib` in the Project Interpreter, but it won't work.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Try installing numpy - `python3 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to install `pip`"? Did the `pip` installation fail? Was `pip` installed, but you can't install modules with it? Can you install other modules, but not `matplotlib` and `numpy`? You should be more specific. Also always post full error messages.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer.
Actually, I don't know how to use the command "python3 -m pip install numpy". In a python file?

I installed successfully pip, numpy and matplotlib in the Default settings panel, and I get the message "Package 'NAME' installed successfully" for each of them.

I also checked if there was any new version of these modules, but it seems that I already up to date.

Any ideas?